# ItemNotMappedException using TFS API on Jenkins build agent

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I am getting the above error on an old build agent but not a new build agent.  The agents are Jenkins.  The build package uses TFS's API to check-in changes that are generated by the build.  The code fails at VersionControlServer.GetItem().

Comment: Did you install the TFS Object Model?

Comment: What's the detail version of the old build agent and new build agent? Why would you  like to still use the old build agent. Since just update the agent will fix the issue.

Comment: The old build slave has VS2012 and I recently installed VS2013.  The new build slave has only VS2013.   I'm thinking that some part of VS2012 is getting used instead of VS2013.  I was looking to add build slaves.

Comment: I think the TFS Object Model is included int Visual Studio.  Is there a separate package?  If so, what should I download?

Answer (score 0):

If the old build agent have both VS2012 and VS2013 installed. Then maybe something wrong  called with VS2012 instead of VS2013 cause the fail.

To make sure the build successful, you should keep your build agent environment be the same with  your local environment.

About TFS Object Model, it's include int Visual Studio. Usually, you don't have to download it individually. There is a separate package, if you want to download it you can through [this link](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/3278bfa7-64a7-4a75-b0da-ec4ccb8d21b6), it's for TFS 2013.